# Почему выходит ошибка когда добавляю медиа фаил в telebot?

Tags: python, telebot

```
    img = open('oppo.png','rb')          # Тут я открываю фаил
bot = telebot.TeleBot('токен') 

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start_message(message=True):
    message_start = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Привет. Я помогу тебе  ')
    keyboard0 = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1)
    keyboard0.add('Меню')
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id,'*Нажми на "Меню" и выбери нужный раздел * ',reply_markup=keyboard0,
                     parse_mode='Markdown')

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def start_message0(message=True):
   if message.text == 'Меню':
       message_start = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Привет. Я помогу тебе  ')
       keyboard = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(row_width=3)
       keyboard.add('Ответы на тесты')
       keyboard.add('Обучающий материал')
       keyboard.add(('Контакты'))

       bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Выбери тему вопроса, ответ на который ты хочешь узнать : ', reply_markup=keyboard)



   if message.text == 'Контакты':
      bot.send_message(message.chat.id, img )    #Тут я пытаюсь его заюзать
```

Сама ошибка выглядит так:

```
2020-04-25 13:51:18,563 (__init__.py:420 MainThread) ERROR - TeleBot: "A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. The server returned HTTP 400 Bad Request. Response body:
[b'{"ok":false,"error_code":400,"description":"Bad Request: strings must be encoded in UTF-8"}']"
```

Хэлп плез :(

Answer (score 0):

Вы используете метод `send_message`, передавая туда байт-строку, представляющую ваше изображение. Для отправки изображений используйте метод `send_photo`:

```
if message.text == 'Контакты':
  bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, img)
```